# Stored Procedure does not retrieve value from data bank and display output in PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, oci8

I have a stored procedure in PHP code that should take an input from the user on a web page. To be specific a product number. Then it should access my data bank table called Lieferung and return the shipping cost for the product. There are no duplicates of the product number in the data bank. The following is a part of my code that refers to the stored procedure

```
 <div>
   <form id='searchabt' action='index.php' method='get'>
    Suche versandkosten zu bestimmter Produktnummer (PINr):
      <input id='PINR' name='PINR' type='text' size='20' value='<?php echo 
$_GET['PINR']; ?>' />
      <input id='submit' type='submit' value='Aufruf Stored Procedure!' />
  </form>
</div>

<?php
  //Handle Stored Procedure for lieferung
  if (isset($_GET['PINR']))
  {
      //Call Stored Procedure   
      $productnumber = $_GET['PINR'];
      $sch="SELECT versandkosten FROM lieferung  WHERE PINr like '%" . 
$_GET['PINR'] . "%'";
          $shippingcost = oci_parse($conn, $sch);
      oci_execute($shippingcost);   

      $sproc = oci_parse($conn, 'begin prod_ship(:p1, :p2); end;');
  //Bind variables, p1=input (productnumber), p2=output (shippingcost)
  oci_bind_by_name($sproc, ':p1', $productnumber);
  oci_bind_by_name($sproc, ':p2', $shippingcost, 20);
  oci_execute($sproc);
  $conn_err=oci_error($conn);
  $proc_err=oci_error($sproc);

  if(!$conn_err && !$proc_err){
     echo("<br><b>" . $productnumber . " hat das Versandkost von. " . 
$shippingcost. "</b><br>" );  // prints OUT parameter of stored procedure
  }
  else{
     //Print potential errors and warnings
     print($conn_err);
     print_r($proc_err);
  }  
}


  // clean up connections
  oci_free_statement($sproc);
  oci_close($conn);
?>
```

versandkosten is a column with varying prices PINr is the product number.

I carried out select statement `SELECT versandkosten FROM lieferung  WHERE PINr like [...]` (an actual PINr value) in SQL and it gave the desired result. I don't know though why in my browser nothing appears. Only the statement with the  actual PINr number "hat das Versandkost von...." appears.

Comment: What is the actual runtime query you're executing?  Your code is *wide open* to **SQL injection**, which is not only a glaring security hole but also a *very* common source of bugs, which is exactly the situation you're in now.  Also, what are all these `oci_*` functions?  When you debug your code, which statement is the first to return an unexpected result?

Comment: That's not a stored procedure but a query.

Comment: @David OCI8 is PHP's original Oracle DB extension ~ http://php.net/manual/book.oci8.php